# UE4 crashing after compiling, anyway to fix?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, visual-studio

I'm working on a small game project and made a completely noob mistake and don't have a back up. Well, after compiling my most recent c++ code, the engine crashed. And now every time I try to reopen it it just crashes. I opened up the Visual Studio files and commented out the code. Is there a way to compile this to the project and get it to open again? I really don't want to have to remake the entire level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rebuild the engine *from* the Visual Studio project files. Just open the `.sln`, find the `.vcxproj` corresponding to your game, right-click it, and pick "Build." "Rebuild" will clean and rebuild the project if you want to be safe (this will take longer).

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you! I was sure there was a way, but I searched around and couldn't figure it out!