# What does rebuilding the .vcxproj file do?

Tags: unreal-4, visual-studio, crash

I'm having the same problem [this user](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139795/ue4-crashing-after-compiling-anyway-to-fix) had.  The solution is confusing me, because all I want to do is comment out the code I added that caused the compiler crash, get Unreal to accept it and stop crashing, but he sounds like he is rebuilding the whole engine, and I just have one crashing project.  I tried commenting out the code and saving the visual studio project, but it didn't change anything.  What is his solution doing?

Comment: The build system doesn't rebuild everything from scratch every time, but caches stuff and does incremental builds (trying to build only what's changed) to shorten the build time. Sometimes it "gets confused", so doing a rebuild forces it to rebuild the whole thing again. There should be a "Rebuild *YourProjectName*" option in Visual Studio.

Comment: I right clicked on my project in Visual Studio, clicked rebuild, and now my project works!  Thanks, feel free to ad you comment as an answer and I'll select it.